# Calculate background-image ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

I have a background-image called `1` at the bottom of my page. I want to show another div with a background-image called `2` over the bottom 5% of background-image `1` (so, not the bottom 30% of the screen but bottom 30% of the image).

However, I have a problem with making this responsive. I think I need to calculate the ratio somehow but I have no idea how. See below for the code I have. Whenever you resize the screen, the size of the background-image `1` changes and the position of the background-image `2` doesn't stay the same. How can I make it stick to one spot no matter what?

JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Jordy8/tmre6pku/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It seems to meet your requirements and is responsive.

```js
$(document).ready(heroResize);
$(window).on('resize', heroResize);

function heroResize() {
  var marginTop = $(window).height() * 0.8;
  $('#layer2').css('margin-top', marginTop);
}
```

```css
#content {
  position: relative;
}

.layer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 1000px;
}

#layer1 {
  background: url('https://cliffsliving.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/CLIFFS_DevilsCourthouse_Shoot_2017_3740_cmyk_brighter_PJ.jpg') center top/contain no-repeat #6DB3F2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#layer2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url('https://www.pngtube.com/myfile/full/9-93924_png-parallax-background-png.png') center bottom/contain repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="layer1" class="layer">
      <div id="layer2" class="layer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question properly but I think you want your layer2 to be wrapped in the layer1 and then use position absolute and bottom: 0 so it always sticks to the bottom and will be position relatively to the parent (in this case that will be layer 1).

Comment: That's precisely what the answer below does, with a working example :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one element, multiple background and `vw` unit without the need of JS. The trick is the value `0.877vw` which is equal to `5% * height of the image` and the the image have a ratio equal to `5.7` and its width will be the window size so `100vw`. We will have then: `0.05 * (100vw/5.7) = 0.877vw`

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.layer{
  height:100vh;
  min-height:60vw;
  background:
    url('https://www.pngtube.com/myfile/full/9-93924_png-parallax-background-png.png') 
     bottom,
    url('https://cliffsliving.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/CLIFFS_DevilsCourthouse_Shoot_2017_3740_cmyk_brighter_PJ.jpg') 
     bottom 0.877vw center;
   background-size:contain;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="layer"></div>
```